# How to automatically test classes that use C# System Class Methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I want to run Unit Tests on some C# classes that call methods from the System Classes. Specifically, in this case, `Image.FromFile();` When I build my main project, everything compiles and runs smoothly, but when I try to run these automated tests, it says it can't find the System Classes. How do I help it "find" these System classes that my main project finds so easily?

I've tried adding References to the Test Project through the Solution Explorer, but the Assembly classes are mysteriously absent from the list of dependencies to choose from.

Here's the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void initTest1()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(new Managers());
}
```

Here's the Managers constructor:

```
public Managers()
{
    //...//
    Image image = Image.FromFile("exit.png");
    //...//
}
```

I expected the test to run, but instead it gave me this error:

```
Message: Test method ManagersTest.initTest1 threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: you should just mock it into its own service.

Comment: @DanielA.White you mean write my own mock `Image` class and `FromFile()` method?

Comment: wrap it into its own service.

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 Your code is tightly coupled to 3rd party implementation concerns that make testing your code in isolation difficult. Consider refactoring your code to decouple those concerns through abstractions.

Comment: @DanielA.White what does it mean to "wrap it into its own service"? put it in its own `namespace`?

Comment: @Nkosi but some method somewhere will have to call these 3rd party implementations. Should I just not test the methods that call them (and the methods that call those methods), or just not ever use the 3rd party implementations? I'm not sure what valid options exist for decoupling them from my code.